# "Error: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required."

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I am using mongoose and Next.js to make the backend of my app. I'm trying to create a push function to insert a new user into my database. I just started to use mongoose so I'm not that good at it, much less how to use mongoose with typescript, but I tried following what the docs have said. I'm have Users as a the main document and Donations as a subdocument to Users. For my post request, I am trying to only create a user with an empty donations array.

```
//users.ts

import mongoose, { Model, Schema, Types } from "mongoose";

interface IItem {
    name: string;
    condition: "poor" | "fair" | "good" | "very good";
}

// Subdocument Interface
interface IDonation {
    date: Date;
    address: string;
    items: Types.Array<IItem>;
}

// Document Interface
interface IUser {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
    donations: IDonation[];
}

type UserDocumentProps = {
    donations: Types.DocumentArray<IDonation>;
};

type UserModelType = Model<IUser, {}, UserDocumentProps>;

// Create Model
// If already created, don't create again
export const User =
    mongoose.models.User ||
    mongoose.model<IUser, UserModelType>(
        "User",
        new Schema<IUser, UserModelType>(
            {
                firstName: String,
                lastName: String,
                email: String,
                password: String,
                donations: [
                    new Schema<IDonation>({
                        date: Date,
                        address: String,
                        items: [{ name: String, condition: String }],
                    }),
                ],
            },
            {
                timestamps: true,
            }
        )
    );
```

```
// api/users/route.ts

import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectMongoDB from "../../../libs/mongodb";
import { User } from "../../../models/users";
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
    const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = await request.json()
    console.log(firstName, lastName, email, password); // prints values
    if (mongoose.connection.readyState === 0) await connectMongoDB(); // if already connected, don't make new connection
    await User.create({ firstName, lastName, email, password }); // error occurs here
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "User Created" }, { status: 201 });
}
```

[image: Postman]

I am getting values from my json request, so that is not the issue. The issue occurs when I try to run User.create({ request values }). I am using postman to make API requests. I there is something wrong about users.ts. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the `donations` field optional:

```
export const User =
    mongoose.models.User ||
    mongoose.model<IUser, UserModelType>(
        'User',
        new Schema<IUser, UserModelType>(
            {
                firstName: String,
                lastName: String,
                email: String,
                password: String,
                donations: {
                  type: [
                      new Schema<IDonation>({
                          date: Date,
                          address: String,
                          items: [{ name: String, condition: String }],
                      }),
                  ],
                  default: [],
                }
            },
            {
                timestamps: true,
            }
        )
    );
```